# Smart tv wifi connection

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

I have a wavlink extender to get wifi from my house to a camper about 75 feet from the house. My question is how can I improve my connection the TV in the camper is a Roku tv and buffers quite a bit when I check my network the TV it says my connection is poor but my download speed is 20mbps or better.Do I need to install a bridge and access point or is there an easier or cheaper way to do it?

Comment: `a wavlink extender` is this inside the "camper"? Is the "camper" basically a tin can?

Answer (score 2):

In this *specific* case - I'd wonder if you have line of sight between the camper and the house.

> I check my network the TV it says my connection is poor but my download speed is 20mbps or better.

How and where are you checking? I also suspect with a regular wifi network, you'd also have poor latency and that's what its complaining about.

[image]

I would also do a site survey - Unifi's wifiman app on a android phone is what I use these days, and working out signal *quality* (and less so in your case, contention)  is an important step

Both those adaptors run through the same connection - 192.168.1.102 is through wireless, and an AP connected to my ONR, and 192.168.2.151 via my 'homelab' router, connected to the network via some regular ethernet.

In my case - the wired connection has much more consistent latency. You might want to compare that between your main house and camper, and ping (and traceroute) are built in tools on most PCs.

In a sense *location* is everything - ideally, if you could trench/bury cable it would be the best, and/or if you had line of sight between two APs

Frankly - the 'cheapest'/Best way to do this is to string a fibre optic (copper sometimes gets lightning strikes) + a pair of low cost media converters and go wired. You can get premade cable, its a little more work ahead of time, and it will give you better/more reliable network than wifi.

While there's point to point, and 'outdoor' wifi access points - which would be the 'right' solution for wireless connections across distance, they're meant for someone longer distances - and probably would cost a bit. The outdoor ones rapidly make more sense if you need to cover a larger space, had other wifi devices that could benefit, and the point to point ones for well, point to point connections. They're pricier and a little more 'prosumer' than the average router or AP though

I'd actually suspect that if you already had mesh networking gear, testing with 2 nodes *outdoors* with line of sight makes sense first. Asus's regular APs do a mesh mode too. Basically use the mesh nodes to bridge the distance and connect the TV to one node via ethernet.

Answer (score -2):

My brother had a 3 device mesh network in his house and he was having similar issues. I replaced them with one Wi-Fi 6 router. After that, he no longer had any issues.

I would recommend you look into buying some Wi-Fi 6E hardware. If you buy 2 Wi-Fi 6E routers you can bridge on the 6Ghz band. You should get a 3 or 4 band router. This maybe a little expensive though.

You can run a cable between the two Wi-Fi routers or plug it directly to the roku. if are looking for a cheaper solution.

You can also bridge Wi-Fi 5 routers as well.
One thing to keep in mind your connection is only as fast as your slowest device. Wi-Fi extenders work best if there at the same level as the main router.

I recommend AUSU Wi-Fi routers.